# Angular component Importing TypeScript class causing jest failure

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I am getting below errow:
● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

C:\Users\ATanna\Desktop\Workspace\DM\delfi-dm-portal\node_modules\dnd-core\dist\esm\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './interfaces';   
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1258:14)
  at ../../node_modules/@angular-skyhook/core/bundles/angular-skyhook-core.umd.js:2:180
  at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@angular-skyhook/core/bundles/angular-skyhook-core.umd.js:5:2)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.528s

This happens when I am trying to import a TypeScript class inside my Angular componentent and initialize it:

```
import { ClauseGenerationUtility } from '../clause-generation.utility.ts'

@Component({
  selector: 'dm-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent {
  private clauseGenerator = new ClauseGenerationUtility()
}
```

This happens when this line:
`private clauseGenerator = new ClauseGenerationUtility()` is executed.

My ***jest.config.js*** is

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'ddm',
  preset: '../../jest.config.js',
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/ddm',
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/AngularSnapshotSerializer.js',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/HTMLCommentSerializer.js'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest'
  }
};
```

Is there anything I am missing?

If I remove this line:
`private clauseGenerator = new ClauseGenerationUtility()` I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: It doesn't like `export * from './interfaces';`. Do you have something like that in your `clause-generation.utility.ts`? Please show the contents of that file (there might be a simple syntax error).

Comment: Or it's something like this: https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/114